# Prove that if P, then $Q → ¬(Q → ¬P)$

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

> Suppose that $P$ is true. Prove that $Q → ¬(Q → ¬P)$ is true.

My attempt:

If $Q$, then statement $\lnot (Q → \lnot P)$ must be true. We know that $P$ is true. For $¬(Q → ¬P)$ to be true, $Q$ must be true. Therefore, given that $P$ is true, statement $Q → ¬(Q → ¬P)$ is true.

Is it correct?  Any suggestions to make it more concise/clear would be welcome.

Comment: may be easier to prove the contrapositive, which is if $P$, then $(Q\implies \lnot P)\implies \lnot Q$

Comment: Say: If $Q$, then WE MUST SHOW THAT statement .....  Don't assume what you are trying to show.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'd thought I *were* using natural deduction, apparently it got messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $Q$, then statement $\lnot (Q → \lnot P)$ must be true. We know that $P$ is true. For $¬(Q → ¬P)$ to be true, $Q$ must be true. Therefore, given that $P$ is true, statement $Q → ¬(Q → ¬P)$ is true.

No, this does not work as a demonstration. Let's analyze your reasoning:

> If $Q$, ...

Your start is ok. That is, given that you need to show $Q \to \neg (Q \to \neg P)$, it makes sense to assume $Q$ is true, and show that in that case $\neg (Q \to \neg P)$ must be true as well.

> ... then statement $\lnot (Q → \lnot P)$ must be true. ...

No. You need to *show* that $\lnot (Q → \lnot P)$ must be true.

> ... We know that $P$ is true. ...

Sure, that is given.

> For $¬(Q → ¬P)$ to be true, $Q$ must be true.

True ... but again you are going the wrong way around. You need to *show* that $\lnot (Q → \lnot P)$ is true ... on the *basis* of the truth of $Q$ (and the truth of $P$)

> Therefore, given that $P$ is true, statement $Q → ¬(Q → ¬P)$ is true.

No, your reasoning hasn't shown this at all.

Comment: Assume $P$ and $Q$ are both true. If $P$ and $Q$ are both true then $\lnot(Q \implies \lnot P)$  is true. Thus $→¬(→¬ )$ is true. Is it correct?

Comment: When I was saying "If $Q$, then statement $\lnot (Q → \lnot P)$ must be true.", what I meant was: "We need to show that if $Q$, then statement $\lnot (Q → \lnot P)$ must be true." But apparently it was unclear.

Comment: @Nelver Yes, that basically works  ... though you don't really *assume* $P$ to be true ... that's a *given*. Also, I would add a few steps to explain a little more. So: Assume $Q$ is true. Then, given that $P$ is true, we have that $\neg P$ is false, and hence $Q \to \neg P$ is false as well. But that means $\neg (Q \to \neg P)$ is true. So, we have shown  that   $\neg (Q \to \neg P)$ is true if we assume $Q$ is true (and given $P$), and therefore we have  $Q \to \neg (Q \to \neg P)$

Comment: @Nelver (re: second comment) Yes, that was put rather poorly.  Likewise, when you say "For $¬(Q → ¬P)$ to be true, $Q$ must be true.", you are showing that if $¬(Q → ¬P)$ is true, then $Q$ must be true, which again is the wrong way around.

Comment: That's my main problem. Although proof itself is really basic, I struggle to find a proper way to explain that. My reasoning was actually identical to yours, yet the way I wrote it was completely unclear.

Comment: @Nelver Yeah, math instructors and books don't always teach students well to properly communicate their reasoning, but that is clearly a very important thing! :)

Comment: "For $¬(Q → ¬P)$ to be true, $Q$ must be true" And what I meant there was, assuming that $Q$ is true, $¬(Q → ¬P)$ will evaluate to true....

Comment: @Nelver I understand, but again: poorly phrased. Consider: it makes sense for me to say: "For Pat to be a bachelor, Pat has to be a male". It makes sense, because that is saying the same as "If Pat is a bachelor, then Pat is male", which is true. But, obviously, "If Pat is a male, then Pat is a bachelor" is not true, because Pat may be married. So, when you say "For [bla bla] to be true, [such and so] needs to be true", you are saying "If [bla bla] then [such and so]", rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Well $Q\to \neg P$ is the same as $\neg Q \vee \neg P$ and then
$$\neg (\neg Q \vee \neg P) \equiv Q \wedge P$$
Again, $Q \to (Q \wedge P)$ is the same as $\neg Q \vee (Q \wedge P)$ and this is the same as
$$(\neg Q \vee Q) \wedge (\neg Q \vee P)$$
Now, $\neg Q \vee Q$ is always true and if $P$ is true, also $\neg Q \vee P$ is true.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat automatic way:
\begin{align}
&P \implies (Q \implies \neg (Q \implies \neg P)) \\
&\neg P \vee (\neg Q \vee \neg (\neg Q \vee \neg P)) \\
&\neg P \vee (\neg Q \vee (Q \wedge P)) \\
&\neg P \vee ((\neg Q \vee Q) \wedge (\neg Q \vee P)) \\
&\neg P \vee (1 \wedge (\neg Q \vee P)) \\
&\neg P \vee (\neg Q \vee P) \\
&(\neg P \vee P) \vee \neg Q \\
&1 \vee \neg Q \\
&1
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove $P\land Q$ implies $\neg(Q\to\neg P)$, which is equivalent to $\neg(\neg Q\lor\neg P)$ and hence $P\land Q$.